# как устроена область видимости?

Tags: java, c++, компиляция, jvm, область-видимости

мучает вопрос, как внутри работает область видимости в различных языках? Ну или хотя бы интересно было бы узнать общую концепцию. как например компилятор си (/c++/c#/java/...) позволяет в разных методах использовать одно и тоже название переменной? меняет "название" переменной на стадии компиляции в зависимости от его родителя? а если два потока одновременно выполняясь читают одну и ту же переменную? ведь потоки могут вызываться в неизвестном для компилятора количестве динамически в реалтайме, так же как и динамически могут создаться в ООП объекты имея внутри одинаковые названия переменных. Чтение исходников JVM и cpython не особо помог

Comment: окей, ну а допустим у меня динамический массив объектов где у объекта есть какая нибудь переменная, как после компиляции можно будет различить адрес переменной в объекте при наличии нескольких его экземпляров? у нас то даже особо названия экземпляра класса явного нет, экземпляров при выполнении мы можем создать сколько угодно, по каким признакам их различать? правда видимо я уже подкрался в полиморфизму

Comment: Во время выполнения никаких имен переменных не существует. Процессор оперирует только адресами. Задача компилятора сгенерировать код, в котором все имена будут заменены адресами, что он и делает.

Comment: И в большинстве компилируемых языков локальные переменные в итоге располагаются на стеке, а стек у каждого потока свой. Так что никаких коллизий между потоками не будет, так как во время выполнения адреса начала стека разные. И если какая то переменная адресуется как ESP+64, то физический адрес получается разный из за разного ESP

Comment: Ну и с объектами абсолютно то же самое. Один экземпляр создается скажем по адресу 100, а другой по адресу 200. во время компиляции компилятор принял решение, что переменная в классе будет по смещению 16 от начала объекта, в итоге в одном объекте она будет 116, в другом 216

Comment: @Mike wow, спасибо. а если в объекте есть нечто динамическое по памяти, то по достижению границы памяти другого объекта происходит перераспределение памяти?

Comment: От языка зависит. В "C" вы сами решаете что сколько занимает и любое превышение приводит к печальным последствиям. Остальные сами решают как себя вести. Вообще объект обычно сразу занимает столько места сколько надо. Структуры не принято делать динамического размера. Все для чего нужна динамическая память в объекте обычно храниться указателями, т.е. хранятся только адреса. А строки да, если выделенный под них буфер закончился, переносятся в другое место (при невозможности расширения) и меняется указатель на эту строку.

Comment: @Mike а за управление памятью (переносом, наделением ссылок и т.д.) отвечает сгенерированная часть программы компилятором (или линкером?) или все делает ОС?

Comment: Обычно за это отвечает стандартная библиотека языка, слинкованная с приложением. Обратите внимание, в языке C нет динамически изменяемых в размере объектов, вообще. Все делается ручками, вызовами alloc/realloc. А различные типы C++ это уже надстройка над C и за каждый тип отвечает стандартная библиотека, где написаны те же самые realloc в нужных местах. А ОС только большие блоки памяти программе выдает по запросу

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Чтобы узнать *общую концепцию*, стоит почитать [книгу дракона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B:_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B,_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B). Здесь попробую осветить в общих чертах работу компилятора Java. Компиляция исходника в байткод проходит в несколько стадий:

1. **Parse**. Читаются исходные файлы, затем токены преобразуются в элементы [абстрактного синтаксического дерева](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE).
2. **Enter**. Строится *таблица символов* путём обхода дерева.
3. **Process** (annotations). Если в компиляции участвуют процессоры аннотаций, то происходит обработка аннотаций, затем, если сгенерировались новые классы, компилятор вновь переходит к стадии Parse.
4. **Attribute**. Синтаксические деревья помечаются атрибутами. На этом этапе происходит разрешение имён, проверка типов, и оптимизация свёртывания констант.
5. **Flow**. Выполняется анализ потока данных. Проверяется правильность присвоений, цепочек вызовов, а также достижимость кода.
6. **Desugar**. Происходит преобразование АСД с целью убрать синтаксический сахар. На этой стадии перечисления преобразуются в специальный класс, а вместо лямбд и ссылок на методы подставляются фабрики и прочие классы из пакета java.lang.invoke.
7. **Generate**. Генерируются class-файлы.

Интересующий вас процесс происходит на стадиях 2, 4 и 5. Центральный элемент этого процесса - [таблица символов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2). Именно по ней компилятор ориентируется при определении, что и где видимо.

Интересный момент в том, что области видимости переменных в Java существуют и имеют значение только на этапе компиляции, в байткоде этой информации уже не будет. Например попытка скомпилировать такой код

```
public static void test() {
    int a = 1;

    {
        int b = 2;
    }

    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

выдаст ошибку "cannot find symbol". Перенесём вывод переменной `b` внутрь блока и скомпилируем код с отладочной информацией `javac -g Example.java`. А теперь заглянем в байткод `javap -c -v -p Example.class`

```
public static void test();
  descriptor: ()V
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
  Code:
    stack=2, locals=2, args_size=0
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_0
       2: iconst_2
       3: istore_1
       4: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       7: iload_1
       8: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      11: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      14: iload_0
      15: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      18: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 52: 0
      line 55: 2
      line 56: 4
      line 59: 11
      line 60: 18
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          4       7     1     b   I
          2      17     0     a   I
```

Благодаря ключу `-g` в самом конце листинга можно увидеть таблицу локальных переменных. JVM эту информацию не использует, для неё есть только слоты - порядковые номера переменных, а об их именах и видимости она ничего не знает. Если опкод `iload_0` по 14-му смещению поменять на опкод `iload_1`, виртуальная машина без зазрения совести выведет в консоль значение "невидимой" переменной `b`.

О полях в байткоде сохраняется чуть больше информации, чем о переменных. Эту информацию компилятор записывает в пул констант - область class-файла до его загрузки и область MetaSpace после загрузки. Каждому полю в пуле соответствует одна запись типа `Fieldref` хранящая разделённые точкой указатели на другие области в пуле. Значение до точки указывает на класс, к которому относится поле, а значение после точки указывает на запись типа `NameAndType`. Запись `NameAndType` в свою очередь тоже хранит два указателя, но уже разделённые двоеточием. Первый указывает на запись хранящую имя поля, а второй на запись хранящую тип. Как говорится, лучше один раз увидеть, чем 100 раз услышать. Скомпилируем, а потом заглянем внутрь этого простого класса:

```
public class Example {
    private int x = 42;

    private int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example obj = new Example();
        obj.getX();
    }
}
```

В самом начале мы увидим пул констант:

```
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #6.#25         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Fieldref           #3.#26         // Example.x:I
   #3 = Class              #27            // Example
   #4 = Methodref          #3.#25         // Example."<init>":()V
   #5 = Methodref          #3.#28         // Example.getX:()I
   #6 = Class              #29            // java/lang/Object
   #7 = Utf8               x
   #8 = Utf8               I
   #9 = Utf8               <init>
  #10 = Utf8               ()V
  #11 = Utf8               Code
  #12 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #13 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #14 = Utf8               this
  #15 = Utf8               LExample;
  #16 = Utf8               getX
  #17 = Utf8               ()I
  #18 = Utf8               main
  #19 = Utf8               ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #20 = Utf8               args
  #21 = Utf8               [Ljava/lang/String;
  #22 = Utf8               obj
  #23 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #24 = Utf8               Example.java
  #25 = NameAndType        #9:#10         // "<init>":()V
  #26 = NameAndType        #7:#8          // x:I
  #27 = Utf8               Example
  #28 = NameAndType        #16:#17        // getX:()I
  #29 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
```

Второй элемент пула констант - это информация о поле `x`. Чуть ниже в листинге можно найти, как JVM понимает из какого именно объекта нужно взять поле:

```
0: new           #3                  // class Example
3: dup
4: invokespecial #4                  // Method "<init>":()V
7: astore_1
8: aload_1
9: invokespecial #5                  // Method getX:()I
12: pop
13: return
```

По смещению 8 располагается опкод `aload_1` загружающий в стек ссылку на объект `obj`. Следом за ним происходит вызов метода `getX`.

```
0: aload_0
1: getfield      #2                  // Field x:I
4: ireturn
```

Первое, что делает метод `getX` - загружает переданную при вызове ссылку на объект в свой кадр стека. Следующий опкод `getfiled` использует эту ссылку, чтобы извлечь значение поля `x` именно из того объекта, на которой она указывает. То есть в псевдокоде получение значения `x` объекта `obj` выглядит примерно так:

```
void main() {
    Example obj = new Example();
    Example.getX(obj);
}

int getX(this) {
    return this.x;
}
```

Comment: спасибо за столь понятный и развернутый ответ! уже примерно понял работу с классами, разумеется на мой вопрос ответ дан.